# Why cannot I call a table function in iSeries DB2 that I just created?

Tags: db2, iseries, functions

Using iSeries Navigator 'Run an sql script' window I created a new table function.
When I go to the Functions branch under the schema where it was created, I see the function among the other few. But when I call the function in the same Run an sql script window, I get an error:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(TESTDAT.FNREPORT(DATE('10/23/2013'), DATE('10/23/2013'), 'ANY')) AS T

SQL State: 42704
Vendor Code: -204
Message: [SQL0204] FNREPORT in TESTDAT type *N not found.
```

Using SquirrelSql client I can see the function in the schema as well, but cannot call it due to the same error.
I can call other functions in the schema, but not the one I just created. What can be the reason?

I can call Generate SQL, copy/paste the schema and function name into query window, and then it will throw the above error.

Update:

Full source code of the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION TESTDAT.FNREPORT ( 
    DATESTART DATE , 
    DATEEND DATE , 
    ICLASS CHAR(3) ) 
    RETURNS TABLE ( 
    A INTEGER )   
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    SPECIFIC TESTDAT.FNCMSREPORT 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    READS SQL DATA 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
    DISALLOW PARALLEL 
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
    ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
    COMMIT = *NONE , 
    DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
    DFTRDBCOL = *NONE , 
    DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
    DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
    SRTSEQ = *HEX   
    BEGIN ATOMIC 
        RETURN 
        SELECT 1 AS A FROM SYSIBM . SYSDUMMY1 ; 
        END  ;
```

Just to clarify that the solutions suggested below did not work.
If the query above was changed to

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(TESTDAT.FNREPORT(DATE('10/23/2013'), DATE('10/23/2013'), CAST('ANY' AS CHAR()3)) AS T
```

or parameter ICLASS removed, or all parameters removed from the function definition, the exact same error was reported.

Comment: A lot of times I find issues with functions and what not if I don't set my schema (library on the iSeries). Also, did you add the schema for the function to your PATH or its equivalent on the iSeries?

Comment: What is 'my PATH'? Other than that, I am still in the same Navigator window I used to create the function. I can create and call a stored procedure in the same manner, but not a function.

Comment: Did you check the SQLSTATE to see what the documentation behind it list? Other thoughts I have are you do not have EXECUTE privelege on a PACKAGE (here is my LUW bent though vs the iSeries that WarrenT can speak better to). I know in LUW there is a PATH, which is what schemas the engine should search through to find the object in question. I think on the iSeries this is called the library list.

Comment: As a creator of this function, I should automatically gain privilege to call it. As a matter of fact, I have ALL privilege checked off, that was the first thing I verified. The permissions on this function are the same as on all that's there.

Comment: All functions, including the newly created one, have the same SET PATH... in generated SQL.

Comment: Function names are resolved, among other things, using their parameter number and types. Make sure that they are what you assume they are: DATE, DATE, and VARCHAR.

Answer (score 2):

As [Heinz Z. did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13414914/505893), I discovered the problem.

One of your function parameters is `char`, while you pass the string literal `'ANY'`, which is considered a `varchar`. The database engine looks for an overloaded version of the function with `varchar` parameters, but doesn't find it.

Solution is either

- changing function parameter to `varchar`
- or cast parameter to `char` in the function call:

  ```
  SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE(TESTDAT.FNREPORT(DATE('10/23/2013'), 
                              DATE('10/23/2013'), 
                              CAST('ANY' AS CHAR(3))
            )) AS T
  ```

If doesn't work, try in any case to remove all parameters from the function and see if *they* are the culprits. Then you can investigate deeper adding one by one, try to work on dates format, for example you can try to pass `current date` instead of 10/23/2013.

Also you must investigate on why it thinks that `FNREPORT` is a **type** and not a function...

Comment: Are you suggesting it should work as this: `SELECT * FROM TABLE(TESTDAT.FNREPORT(DATE('10/23/2013'), DATE('10/23/2013'), CHAR('ANY', 3))) AS T`?

Comment: This is what I get back from that call: `Error: [SQL0204] FNREPORT in TESTDAT type *N not found.
SQLState:  42704
ErrorCode: -204`

Comment: I get exact same error message even if I completely remove the 3d parameter.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: No parameters - same error.

Answer (score 1):

Start with this statement before trying to execute the function:

```
SET PATH TESTDAT;
```

Comment: Same error message. The only thing that's changed is that with `SET PATH` I can call my SPs without specifying schema.

Comment: What's the source for your UDTF?

Comment: If you look in iNavigator, does it show the function is there, and defined as you expect?

Comment: Yes to all, and not only in navigator. Like I said - I can see function information thru SquirrelSql, but cannot call it. I am updating full source of the function in the original question.